# Check if a device is been used by a user

Tags: embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, software-design, user-experience

I have a device that has accelerometer, Bluetooth and a controller which has RTC in it. I want to know if a user is using the device or has stopped using it.

I have a wearable device which can be used standalone or through mobile app. Firmware and app has bugs which I keep on fixing. When device is used from mobile app, I can get info whether device is used or not and now I want to know if a user is using the device as a standalone or has completely stopped using it. In standalone variant, user can connect to mobile app for firmware update.

I am not targeting/tracking a particular user or something, nowhere to invade user piracy. I just want users to keep benefiting and using the device.

How can I know if user is using the device or has stopped using  it? Roughly; I want to find user retention when device isn't connected to mobile or internet.

Edit: Device doesn't have an EEPROM or some storage. One way was to get time from RTC and save it in storage. When device is connected to mobile via BLE, I can get the info in standalone version otherwise it will keep on rewriting over existing data until connected to mobile.

Comment: _"When device is used from mobile app, I can get info whether device is used or not ..._" What stops you from using the same information stand-alone?

Comment: @thebusybee Since the device is at user end and there is no WiFi or something through which device can communicate remotely, I am unable to get info in standalone version. When device is connected to mobile, data is collected in mobile app and sent over server through which I can find if it is used or not.
e.g. smart watch. I can use it as a conventional watch and never ever connect to mobile except to sync time or for updating firmware or I can connect to mobile to track my daily walk/run or other activity.